# Windows: How to get sum of CPU time used even for closed programs?

Tags: windows, task-manager

I have a home server, and it does a lot of stuff (gets hot, fans run loudly) when idle. Once I log on, whatever it was doing stops, and so I cannot find a reason.

If I could see a sum of CPU times for all programs that were running during the day, I guess I could easily see what is keeping the sever busy.

How can I do this?

Comment: [This PowerShell-Article](https://www.petri.com/powershell-problem-solver-process-cpu-utilization) seems to be a good starting point: `Get-Process | Sort CPU -descending | Select -first 5 -Property ID,ProcessName,CPU | format-table -autosize` and then save the results to some CSV/XMP/JSON-file.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I wouldn't be debugging scripts, but as a last resort ... :)

Comment: Windows spy program. When you are not there, it processes, packs and sends.